# PHP-accept arrays as argument and return array alphabetically

Tags: php

array of random strings e.g.

```
<?php
%data = array ('htmk','tsjd',gdyd',hsua',); //and so forth with more random strings
?>
```

How to accept them as arguments and sort alphabetically, with codes to display as a webpage

Comment: Sort the single values of the array or the first letter?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `%data` with a `%` sign? You're one character over on your keyboard ;-)

Answer (score 0):

From what I could understand, you want to sort the array alphabetically and display it as HTML code.

Try this:

```
$data = array('html','tsjd','gdyd','hsua');
//The sort() function does the trick.
sort($data);

foreach ($data as $value)
{
    echo $value.'<br />';
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: You can't `foreach(sort($data))` like that. `sort` returns `true`/`false`. It'd need to be `sort($data); foreach($data)`

Comment: Sorry. I forgot sort() uses a reference to the variable. Already fixed the code. Thanks.